# How to fetch the alt value from an img using vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

Am trying to fetch the price table from [this page](http://www.idealo.co.uk/compare/351072/canon-500d-77mm-close-up-lens.html)

For this I have the following code:

Everything is working fine only the img alt tag of the last column is not displaying in the. This code is perfectly fine only the last column's class is not fetched.

```
Sub TableExample()

Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim strURL As String

    If Range("B2").Value <> "NA" Then
        strURL = "http://www.idealo.co.uk/compare/351072/canon-500d-77mm-close-up-lens.html"
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With IE
            '.Visible = True
            .navigate strURL
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Set doc = IE.document
            GetAllTables doc
            .Quit
        End With
    End If

End Sub

Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
        rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        On Error GoTo Err1:
        If tabno = 10 Then
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                colno = 6
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    If colno = 6 And nextrow > 10 Then
                        Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("cellborder")
                        Set imgTgt = classColl(nextrow - 11).getElementsByTagName("img")
                        rng.Value = imgTgt(0).getAttribute("alt")
                    Else
                        rng.Value = cl.innerText
                    End If
                    Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                    colno = colno + 1
                Next cl
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -i)
                '     Call trim1
                i = 0
            Next rw
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next tbl

Err1:
'Call comp
'    ws.Cells.ClearFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: It's `getElement**s**ByClassName`, so your `classColl` should be a collection or something like that, so you might want to try `classColl(0).getElementsByTagName("img")`.

Comment: i did it but the result is same...no change

Comment: Kindly make your code readable when you post it here. It's difficult to figure out what's going on with your code if you don't indent and write it properly. :) I've edited it for you this time. :)

Comment: @bk201 thanks dear...since am new to this forum have really li'l idea about the formats nowon I will follow the rules

Comment: That's alright. What is this supposed to do? Are you trying to get the images for Amazon, etc? Can you please post a screenshot of the elements you are targeting?

Comment: am trying to get the whole pricing table in that page.i can fetch the whole table except the shop name from the last column...i want to fetch the alt tag of those shop's image...

Comment: @BK201 if i remove this following part and keep everything same then i will get the whole table is fetched except the shop's name         'Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("cellborder")
'Set imgTgt = classColl(nextrow - 13).getElementsByTagName("img")(1)
'rng.Value = imgTgt(1).getAttribute("alt")

Comment: The macro is returning the wrong values to me. All that I see are `Table1`, `Table2`, etc. Are you sure your link and macros are correct and working for you?

Comment: if you remove the following lines it will return you the price table of the page without the shop's name 'Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("cellborder") 'Set imgTgt = classColl(nextrow - 13).getElementsByTagName("img")(1) 'rng.Value = imgTgt(1).getAttribute("alt")

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48411/discussion-between-user3305327-and-bk201)

Comment: @BK201 have u tested this at your end...is my code returning the value without shop names

Comment: am still hopping around the loops...can anybody help me on this issue please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (very dirty) variation for your `GetAllTables` subroutine:

```
Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Improvised way of getting images.
    Dim imagesColl As New Collection
    Set imgColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("noborder")
    For Each imgElem In imgColl
        If imgElem.getAttribute("height") = 30 And imgElem.getAttribute("width") = 80 Then
            imagesColl.Add imgElem.getAttribute("alt")
        End If
    Next imgElem

    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        If tabno = 10 Then
            nextrow = 1
            imgIter = 1
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                colno = 1
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    Set rng = ws.Cells(nextrow, colno)
                    If colno = 5 Then
                        rng.Value = imagesColl.Item(imgIter)
                        imgIter = imgIter + 1
                    Else
                        rng.Value = cl.innerText
                    End If
                    colno = colno + 1
                Next cl
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Next rw
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next tbl

End Sub
```

Thing is, you don't really have to do it table style. If you know which elements to target, creating a collection for the data outside of the DOM (that is, using *normal* VBA collections) is much better IMHO.

Anyway, above is ***tried and tested***. Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify which `ClassColl`'s image to lookup.

Try this:

```
Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("cellborder")
Set imgTgt = classColl(0).getElementsByTagName("img")
Rng.Value = imgTgt(0).getAttribute("alt")
```

Comment: tried it but no difference...i think i should share the whole code with you...am editing the question please check once