# How to extract alt value from an image using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to extract alt value from this code:

```
<div class="item-right">
            <div class="item-company-logo-wrapper">
                <div class="item-company-logo">
                    <img class="centered" src="https://jrdportals.s3.amazonaws.com/6bd8ed9bdba5432c98b1c12a5fada6a8_logo" alt="XYZ Company">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-buttons">
```

I use below code but it is extracting full html code but I need only "XYZ Company" (or value in alt)

```
Case "item-company-logo" 
sht.Range("l" & RowCount + 1) = obj.innerHTML
```

I tried using `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` but no value has been extracted. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
obj.innerHTML
```

to

```
obj.Alt
```

Comment: That's because you're using the `<div>` object, but you should be using the `<img>` object.

Comment: I am new to VBA, so if you could tell me how to use ' <img>' object

Comment: It's html DOM you need to know, not really VBA - however you got the `<div>` element in your current code, you need to use that same method to grab the `<img>` element instead. That's not what the question is about though

Comment: @MacroMan - I came across your answer after it has been flagged as VLQ. I suggest you edit your answer and explain a bit more what's going on: why the problem happens, and why your suggestion should work (which is pretty much what you did in the comments anyway).

Comment: @Dev-iL appreciate the feedback, and completely agree - but as the OP hasn't provided further feedback I'm probably just going to delete the answer.

Comment: Couldn't able to understand the answers as i am very new to VBA 
I tried researching more and encountered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008004/how-to-fetch-the-alt-value-from-an-img-using-vba?rq=1
but that too is not working
Thanks appreciate your help @MacroMan